# Do I need Transit visa of Finland even I have Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen-visas

I am an Indian citizen traveling to Denmark. I have a connecting flight from Helsinki (Finland) to Denmark (stopover 3 hours in Helsinki). I have a Schengen Visa given by Denmark of Type C.

**Question:** Do I need Transit visa of Finland?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You'll enter the Schengen Area in Finland (i.e. go through immigration), and then the flight to Denmark is internal in Schengen (very similar to domestic flights).